# I got some error on unresolved reference on methods when there is nullable variable?

Tags: kotlin

I am practicing Kotlin nullable but I got a problem of unresolved reference on some of the methods I called. I'm not sure what is the problem, I had tried Google, and try to rebuild and clean the project, add in kotlin-android-extensions in build.gradle but still the same problem.

Problem example:

```
fun main(){
    var nullableName : String? = "Test"
    nullableName = null                       //1.  whenever this line is not comment

    nullableName?.let { println(it.length) }  //2. .length will have unresolved reference
}
```

or

```
fun main(){
     var nullableName : String? = "Neo"
     nullableName = null                      //1.  whenever this line is not comment

     print(nullableName!!.toLowerCase())      //2. .toLowerCase() will have unresolved reference
}
```

Comment: In your second code block you have `func`. Did you mean `fun` and that was simply a typo?

Comment: Seems like the compiler just gave up inferring the type when it realises the code is unreachable, which is rather weird. `nullableName?.let<String, Unit> { println(it.length) }` works.

Comment: Likewise, `(nullableName!! as String).toLowerCase()` works too, but note that `toLowerCase` is deprecated.

Comment: @Slaw ohh im so sorry, that was just a typo.

Comment: @Sweeper i tried ```(nullableName!! as String).toLowerCase()``` this, but same, it's still the same error.

Comment: Well I can confirm the problem occurs, and that explicitly defining the types does "fix" it. I would probably consider this a bug. Consider submitting a bug report to Kotlin's developers (assuming one doesn't already exist for this).

Comment: @Sweeper ya it's weird for this one ```nullableName?.let { println(it.length) }```, not sure is my kotlin version and gradle version are not compaticle, but i tried to find on kotlinlang, its compatible with kotlin 1.4.32, Gradle Version 6.7.1

Comment: @Slaw cool cool, i will submit a bug report, but i will search if there is similar report first.

Comment: Note I see the problem with Gradle 6.7.1 + Kotlin 1.4.32, Gradle 7.1 + Kotlin 1.4.32, and Gradle 7.1 + Kotlin 1.5.20 (latest of both).

Comment: @Slaw ohh really, do you have the link for that? I will be very appreciated to see it.

Comment: Tested it on my own computer.